# Ionic 3 Angular 4 Cannot find module `jsonwebtoken`

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ionic3

I'm trying to import `jsonwebtoken` from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jsonwebtoken) but I getting the error `Cannot find module 'jsonwebtoken'`. in a Ionic 3 app.

I already to `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm install` or `yarn install` and my App still not finding this module. I checked too if `node_modules/@types/jsonwebtoken` is downloaded and is there.

I'm importing it this way:

```
import * as JWT from "jsonwebtoken";
```

I thanks in advance in any help.

Comment: Please show us how do you import this module.

Comment: Oh sorry! Just add it!

Comment: The dir you gave is for `TypeScript` see `@types/...`. You have to check if there is standalone dir `jsonwebtoken`directly in `node_modules`.

Comment: Also check if it exist in `package.json` or you install with param `--save` or `--save-dev`?

Comment: I have only this directory. `"@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.3"` exists in my `package.json`. I found this [issue](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/199) telling that this package is only avaliable in node.js. This is why I can't find this module in angular?

Comment: Look like you are right, this package can be used on node side. Use this [jwt-deocde](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode). However I think it should be in node modules.

Comment: Maaate, you are only installing typings XD, Previously I searched in google for `jsonwebtoken`, and now I clicked in your link and it's for typgins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are installing only `typings` see in you link you have `@types/jsonwebtoken`, by installing this you only have supported `types` in this for your `IDE`. However `jsonwebotken` is for server side. To decode token on client side use `jwt-decode`. Get it from this [repo](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode) or `npm install jwt-decode --save` and then `import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-deocde'`. However for angular there is special package. Get it from [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) or `npm install angular2-jwt --save`

Comment: Thanks for the complete awnser! But I want to encode a JSON. Do you know a package for?

Comment: If I may ask for what purpose? Do you just want to encrypt data? To encode token you need a secret key which is gonna be exposed on the client side.

Comment: Yes, I'm realizing that I have a bad ideia to use JWT. I want to send a request with the user password. My team and I just decided to use SSL + HTTPS to do this.